# Adding a New Column to Partion By on a very large, poorly partition table in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to databricks and was curious if there is a better way to add a column to partition by on a very large table.

I have a poorly partition table that is now over 1.5 tb in size.  The current partition column too wide (only 15 distinct values).  Partition pruning does occur, but it files underneath are still a little to large to process in a timely matter.

I want to add a new column to the table to partition by (a DATE column)  After experimenting some of the default suggestions, I am running into some timeout / internal errors when trying to add the column and save the table.

Sample of the code I used, formal names removed to protect the innocent.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df = spark.read.table("schema.table")
df_update = df.withColumn("new_date_column",expr("CAST(date_time_column AS date)"))
df_update.write.format("delta") \
          .mode("overwrite")
          .option("overwriteSchema", True)\
          .partitionBy("current_partition","new_date_column") \
          .saveAsTable("schema.table")
```

I am getting what appears to be the equivalent to a timeout on the cluster I am running on after 4 hours of processing.

I have done the following pattern on several smaller tables and it worked rather well.
https://docs.databricks.com/delta/best-practices.html

Any input and/or insight is appreciated.

Comment: It could be many possible causes for the timeout. You need to check spark UI to understand why job failed or still running. Then try to investigate failure reason and allocate more executors.

Comment: it also depends on where the data resides. For example, you may have problems if you're using credentials passthrough

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it's common for an out-of-memory condition in spark to present an error message that looks like a timeout.  If this code works great on smaller tables, but falls over on the large table, start watching resources to make sure that it's not spiking resource requirements at some point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).